# Will I be able to play Destiny's daily/weekly heroic and nightfalls anymore without the expansion

Tags: ps4, destiny

The 1st expansion of Destiny went live this week.  I have not purchased the expansion yet.  The Daily and Weekly heroic quests and Nightfall show locked now.  I'm not sure if I want to purchase the Expansion especially if parts of the game are going to be disabled if I don't keep up with purchasing the expansions.

Comment: From the sounds of it this week is unique since its a launch week. But I imagine they will switch between base content and expansion. But as there are more expansions it will be less and less likely that base content will be featured. With that said, I have a feeling this question might technically be off topic though since it focuses on developer intent (I believe would be the right category.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will. The daily and weekly activities will rotate between original and expansion content. According to the [Bungie Weekly Update this week](http://www.bungie.net/7_Bungie-Weekly-Update---12112014-/en/News/News?aid=12465):

> Daily and Weekly Heroic Activities
>   - Featured activities will rotate between old and new
>   - Next week will feature Destiny launch content

Comment: Dang it.  Rotation sounds like I'll only be able to play every other week. :(

Comment: @SeanB given that there is only 1 strike and 3 missions in The Dark Below, odds are it will be more often than that. Guess time will tell.